# Oracle APEX + AJAX character coding

Tags: ajax, oracle, character-encoding, oracle-apex

I'm trying to pass text variables as parameters using `htmldb_Get`. Unfortunately when I'm updating or inserting rows whitch contains accented characters like `é` the result in the database will be `ÃŠ`. I'm only developing this application for the firm so any solution altering the installed database or APEX properties won't help.

JS code:

```
var ajaxRq = new htmldb_Get(null,&APP_ID.,'APPLICATION_PROCESS=updateCategory',0);
ajaxRq.addParam('x01','é');
ajaxRes = ajaxRq.get();
```

Comment: Are you inserting data into a `VARCHAR2` or an `NVARCHAR2` column?  What is the database and national character set?  Does the accented character you're trying to insert exist in the database character set?

Comment: column :VARCHAR2NLS_CHARACTERSET: EE8ISO8859P2, NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET: AL16UTF16. For the third question I don't know how to answer.

Comment: Wikipedia has a nice table of the characters in each character set.  Here is the page with the ISO-8859-2 character set http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2.  My guess is that you're trying to save character 223 (0xE9) in that character set but it would be useful to confirm that.  What character set is your web page rendered in?

Comment: Yep. That is the 'é' (é - 00E9 233).
It's APEX, so I'm only adding elements and code. If I retrive data, or append element with these types of characters it's ok. Only inserting/updating using ajax (and dynamic process) causes this behaviour.

Comment: To answer the question: in the meta tag it describes the charset as 8859-2.